# Unity AssetBundle get memory device (ROM, Total Memory)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory

How get Total memory or ROm memory device?
I load AssetBundle from the server, I need to check if there is enough memory to load or not. I ask to give an answer in mind C # code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow... What have you tried?

Comment: I did not understand you

Comment: Well.. If you read [ask] [tour] [mcve] you will soon see that SO doesnt just hand out code, tutorials and so on, we are here to help not do things for you.  Part of your question should form the what you did and hasnt worked, if you havent done anything, its not a SO question.. As we dont provide links to tutorials